# Itunes Connect won't accept my Screenshots

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Can't understand why the image below in the link is getting rejected by Itunes Connect when trying to upload images for my screenshots.

I'm having the same problem for the app Icon as well.

http://postimg.org/image/qo66xecsh/

I've read the dimensions for teh 3.5in and made the image so. It is also a Jpg and is of 72res and RGB obviously without a transparent background.

Very confused. Gladly accept someone's help.

Comment: I guess you have read all this right? Make sure follow exactly the guideline and provide specific screenshots/images for different screen sizes/ devices. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html

Comment: Yeah I've already been through that... Maybe I need to go over it again Cheers